# npm install gives different result in different computers

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node project that produces different results on npm install on different computers.

The project is available at: 
https://github.com/guy-mograbi-at-gigaspaces/gs-ui-ks

On my machine, npm finishes without errors. My details are:

```
 - node 0.10.7
 - npm 1.3.9
```

On another team member's computer it produces the following error:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.5.4 wants karma@~0.9.4 || ~0.10
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-mocha@0.0.4 wants karma@~0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.2 wants karma@>=0.9.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-requirejs@0.2.1 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.1.2 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.1 wants karma@>=0.9

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd c:\buildserver\buildagent\workspace\root\ui\build-node-project\build-ks
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\buildserver\buildagent\workspace\root\ui\build-node-project\build-ks\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

We both have windows 7. I would like to avoid the statement `it works on my machine`. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it in the future?

EDIT:

FYI - to resolve this we changed all dependencies to "*" (latest version). However, I would like to get to bottom of the difference to avoid future breaks and emberrasments.

Comment: Have you a npm module with specific dependent binaries ? Or his path is different than yours ?

Comment: nothing special we are aware about. What should we check?

Comment: It looks like you have different versions of `node` and `npm`

Comment: I am quite certain this is not the problem as the major version is the same. I will make both environments the same and then I will update you on the matter.

Comment: check your PATH env var and his PATH env var. Check required binaries in your post and in his post. And try this on his post : 
`npm cache clean`

Answer (score 2):

@throrin19 is correct that the immediate answer is to rm -rf node_modules/karma-* and re-install in this case.

and you are also correct that the difference between environments is previous karma installations.

I debugged a very similar problem today and learned:

- npm (1.3.17) will not attempt to install a dependency that is already installed when the installed version still satisfies the version specified in package.json
- npm will, of course, go and try to find dependencies that have been added recently

i.e. local npm repos are quite susceptible to temporal oddities with the exact contents of a repo highly-dependent on when you populated that repo, how strictly dependency versions are specified, the rate of change of dependencies, and the strictness of your depdendency-maintainer's notion of semantic versioning

In my case,

1. we have been using karma for a long time were currently-using ~0.10.8, with 0.10.9 on my system before I rm -rf'd node_modules
2. a colleague working on a feature added karma-mocha ^0.1.3 to package.json on a branch weeks ago, but this allows for an update to karma-mocha 0.1.4; unfortunately, this doesn't work because karma-mocha 0.1.4 depends on karma ~0.12.0, which currently resolves to 0.12.8

lots of debugging ensued for me today after that feature was merged and it hit my machine.

the solution we are using is:

1. lock-down dependency versioning, especially if important; semver is nice and all, but dealing with SNAPSHOTs in the Java ecosystem indicates semver may fail to scale
2. include options in my tooling to perform important builds with more-hygienic environments, deleting caches like node_modules; these tools run frequently-enough that we will spot issues quickly

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is with karma. In Google, i try your error message and, in first result, i find this :

> Sorry, I know this sucks and it's a confusing error. We need to fix this in NPM.
>
> In the meantime, just remove all the modules (rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-*) and install Karma again.

Source : https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/716

Comment: So your explanation to the difference between environments is previous karma installations?

Comment: my comment is older than this response